# Ubuntu: Forward browser via ssh in putty

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, firefox, browser, putty

For a uni project, I need access to the Spark UI, but I'm really at a loss at how I can do it or if it's even possible.

Here's the setup.

With putty I access a jump server via ssh, and from there, I get to the actual Spark server via ssh. It's all set up, and the history server is reachable (I checked with the w3m browser). But I need an 'actual' browser with JavaScript capabilities to use the Spark UI, which I need for statistics.

I've already installed firefox, and currently it says 'no DISPLAY environment variable specified'.

So, this is the situation, and again, I really don't have the slightest idea how I could get firefox on the Spark server to work and then actually have access on the webpage, since I have to somehow get it to the jump server and then to me. If anyone could help, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have two "easy" tunneling strategies, you can tunnel X11, or the spark server traffic.

tunnel X11:

```
mybox$ ssh -X box1
box1$ ssh -X box2
box2$ firefox # (must be an X11 version browser)
```

tunnel the Spark port:

```
mybox$ ssh -L 7077:localhost:7077 box1
box1$ ssh -L 7077:localhost:$SPARKPORT box2
box2$
```

Now you can point a web browser on your machine to localhost:7077 and it will create a connection to box2:$SPARKPORT

I like to tunnel ports rather than X11 traffic so you get to use the same browser you normally use.   Up to you.

Comment: Holy smokes, it worked! Thank you very much!
I couldn't get the first solution to work with that whole "Error: no DISPLAY environment variable specified" ordeal, but the 2nd solution worked at the first try.
I now can see the web interface on my local browser. Thanks again!